# Is it possible to create and connect Django databases from the application?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-database

Is it possible to create and connect Django databases from the application?

An example.

In a system at the time of user registration, at that time django create a new database generates the migrate and create a new database with the exact settings.

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a new database per user?

Comment: I am not sure if it will help but you can read about how to achieve multi-tenancy in Django.

Comment: Raydel Miranda, yes. Because every user will be a company to me. And every company has its own particularities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['base.routers.routers.TenantRouter']


MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'base.middleware.middleware.Multidb',
    ...
]
```

---

```
def Multidb(get_response):

def middleware(request):

    try:
        usuario = request.user
        empresa = usuario.empresa
    except:
        empresa = request.GET['empresa']


    @thread_local(using_db=empresa)
    def execute_request(request):
        return get_response(request)

    response = execute_request(request)

    return response

return middleware
```

---

```
class TenantRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return get_thread_local('using_db', 'default')

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return get_thread_local('using_db', 'default')

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        return True

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        return True
```

---

```
class thread_local(object):
    """ a decorator that wraps a function in a thread local definition block
    useful for passing variables down the stack w/o actually passing them
    examples: what database to read from, whether to cache queries, etc
    adapted from django.test.utils.override_settings
    Usage:
    @thread_local(SITE_NAME_SHORT='foobar')
    def override(request):
        ...
    """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.options = kwargs

    def __enter__(self):
        for attr, value in self.options.items():
            setattr(threadlocal, attr, value)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        for attr in self.options.keys():
            setattr(threadlocal, attr, None)

    def __call__(self, test_func):

        @wraps(test_func)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            # the thread_local class is also a context manager
            # which means it will call __enter__ and __exit__
            with self:
                return test_func(*args, **kwargs)

        return inner


def get_thread_local(attr, default=None):
    """ use this method from lower in the stack to get the value """
    return getattr(threadlocal, attr, default)
```